# Login social utilizando API em Laravel com Socialite para ser consumida em um aplicativo em Flutter

Tags: laravel, api, flutter

Estou desenvolvendo uma API utilizando Laravel 5.8 para ser consumida em um aplicativo flutter. Sendo assim, estou utilizando o Laravel Socialite para realizar o login com o Facebook e Google. Porém, ainda sou novo nesses frameworks e não sei como realizar o login no aplicativo através da api com o laravel socialite.

Utilizei esse trecho de código para o site e funcionou.

```
class SocialAuthController extends Controller
{
    public function redirect($social)
    {
        return Socialite::driver($social)->redirect();
    }

    public function callback($social)
    {
        $user = SocialAccountService::createOrGetUser(Socialite::driver($social)->stateless()->user(), $social);

        auth()->login($user);

        return redirect()->to('/');
    }
}
```

Alguém pode me indicar algum material ou uma solução para criar uma API em laravel utilizando Socialite para que no aplicativo Flutter eu consiga consumir essa api e de alguma forma receber os dados do usuário como retorno dessa api?

Comment: Fala Mateus. Talvez isso ajude: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35966605/using-laravel-socialite-with-an-api